# Should I block non-work-related websites?

Tags: websites

To improve productivity at my company, I'm considering blocking non-work related websites. This includes social media sites like Facebook and news sites - basically sites that tend to be time killers.

I'm considering either a straight out block or maybe sending an email around saying certain websites are prohibited and that work policy is that all internet traffic is logged.

I'm also happy to make exemptions for anyone who can prove they need any sites for work purposes.

Basically, the aim is to increase productivity but I'm afraid it'll kill morale. I also don't mind people taking the odd break here and there to have a look - but walking around the office, sometimes I can see quite a lot of people wasting work time on these sites. Which is why I think an outright ban might just be easier instead of having to police everyone.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: You might actually decrease productivity (of others by them searching for ways to get around the ban and of yourself for all those petty requests for having stuff un-banned).

Comment: Are you the owner or manager? If not, mind your own business and productivity issues.

Comment: That's one way to reduce your salary expenditure.

Comment: Cellphone hotspots, VPN and online proxies are a thing, so I can't imagine this will have any effect beyond just being annoying.